# module 'django.db.models.fields' has no attribute 'subclassing'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, webhooks

Here’s a sample model to hold a bunch of generic information related to the webhook event. I'm working on a problem in which I have to convert django code to Django rest framework. Here is a link if you want to refer [here](https://medium.com/@raiderrobert/how-to-make-a-webhook-receiver-in-django-1ce260f4efff)
Now I'm trying to write it in Django Rest Framework. After creating a serializer.py file, I'm getting this error:-

> class HStoreDescriptor(models.fields.subclassing.Creator):
>   AttributeError: module 'django.db.models.fields' has no attribute
>   'subclassing'

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQH2e.png)

[serializer.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q5Ux.png)

Comment: dont post images place your code in question with codeblocks

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Comment: Django 2.1.7 in this. If I use Django 1.9 will it work?

Comment: Well if version is causing the problem, then you can try changing the version.

Comment: If I changed the version. It's showing No module name django.urls. I tried replacing with other but it's not working. In this case what can we do?

Answer (score 0):

In django 2.1, you have to add `django.contrib.postgres` to your `installed_apps` in order to use HSStoreField. Also, you might need to create a migration with an extension. See here: [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield)

Comment: I did add django.contrib.postgres in my installed apps. Can you see the code and tell me what changes I can do?

Comment: Did you add the extension on the migrarion file?

Comment: I didn't understand exactly how to do it!

Comment: It is pretty clear on the docs. You need to add `HStoreExtension()` on the operations section on your migrations. See here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#create-postgresql-extensions

Just remember that you need to unapply the migration and add it again. Or create a new migration.

Comment: If I change the version from 2.1 to 1.9 then will it work?

Comment: Possibly. But it is possible that you will need to downgrade other dependencies as well.

Comment: Yeah now I'm getting this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.urls' .

Comment: After using django 1.9